# How to trim first 3 character from a string in swift

Tags: swift

I have a dropdown(userCphList) in which there are 2 value : 66/001/0004, 66/002/9765. I want to trim the selected value of dropdown from 66/001/0004 to 001/0004.

Given below is my code:

```
userCphList.didSelect{(selectedText , index ,id) in  
            let cphid = selectedText  
            let url = self.appDelegate.BaseUrl + "geojson/proj_4326?cph_id=" + cphid  
            self.get_wl_geojsondata(url: url)  
        }
```

I want to get cphid as 001/0004.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank You!
Rutuparna Panda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string where separator is a slash, drop the first component and then join it again:

```
let str = "66/001/0004"
let trimmed = str.split { $0 == "/" }
    .dropFirst()
    .joined(separator: "/")   // "001/0004"
```

Another option is to find the first slash index and get the substring after it:

```
if let index = str.firstIndex(of: "/") {
    let trimmed = str[str.index(after: index)...]   //  "001/0004"
     // or simply dropping the first character
     // let trimmed = str[index...].dropFirst()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of characters to be dropped is fixed the easiest way is `dropFirst`

```
let string = "66/001/0004"
let trimmedString = String(string.dropFirst(3))
```

Other ways are Regular Expression

```
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\d+/", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

and removing the substring by range

```
if let range = string.range(of: "/") {
    let trimmedString = String(string[range.upperBound...])
}
```